# Caesar cipher without knowing the Key

Tags: python, python-2.7, caesar-cipher

Hey guys if you look at my code below you will be able to see that i was able to create a program that can open a file decode the content of the file and save it into another file but i need to input the key every time but what if i don't know they key how can i calculate the key using the frequency analysis.

```
import sys

def decrypt(cipher, key):

plain = ""
for index in range(len(cipher)):
    if cipher[index].isalpha():

        if cipher[index].isupper():
            plain = plain + chr((ord(cipher[index]) - 64 - key) % 26 + 64)


        elif cipher[index].islower():
            plain = plain + chr((ord(cipher[index]) - 96 - key) % 26 + 96)

    else:
            plain = plain + cipher[index]

return plain

in_filename = sys.argv[1]
key = int(sys.argv[2])
out_filename = sys.argv[3] 

with open(in_filename, "r") as f:
    encrypted = f.read()

decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key)

with open(out_filename, "w+") as f:
    f.write(decrypted)
```

Comment: help with what exactly??

Comment: Sorry we need more information to help you... have you already have some code you can post ?

Comment: If you're decrypting text from a known language you can just try every possible key and see how many of the resulting words are in a word list of that language.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Bruce forcing is always an option in Cryptography and is therefore ignored when it comes to breaking an encryption. (Actually, the weakness of an encryption algorithm is measured by about how much you can decrease the keyspace compared to a bruteforce attack.)

Comment: i have added the code at the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Caesar-Cipher is a linear substitution cipher. 
Explanation:

Have *p* be your plaintext.
Have *k* be our numerical key (<26 for the sake of this explanation).
Have *c* be one character in *p*. 
Have *I(c)* be the index of *c* in  *p*.
Have *fc(i)* be a function which maps an index *i* to it's letter in the alphabet. 
Have *e(c)* be the 'encrypted' character of c.

Then:

*e(c) = fc( I(c) + k)*

Or in plain English: Each characters gets shifted by the value of *k*. It's therefore a Linear substitution since it always gets shifted by the same amount and the characters are substituted.

The problem with this encryption algorithm is, that you don't really scramble the plaintext or add entropy. 
(In harsh words, the Caesar-Cipher is closer to an encoding rather than an encryption).

Given that, we know that all matching letters in our cipher-text substitute for the exact same plain-text character.

This means, you'll be able to run statistical analysis on your Cipher-text and simply analyse the letter distribution. Different sounds/letters occur different amount of times.

So how do we apply this technique?

Based on your name, I'd guess you are German and I'll just assume that your Cipher-text is as well.

In German, the most common letters are E and I.

We're almost there!

Now, you could simply find the most common letter in your cipher-text and calculate the difference between that letter and E (difference between their indexes, of course). That will yield you the secret key!

Here is a code example:

```
"""
This module aims to break Caesar-ciphers from German plaintext
based     on statistics of letter distribution.

The caesar cipher is a character substitution algorithm.
Bob chooses a number as the key n.
Bob then shifts every character of the plain-text by n, cycling  
through the entire alphabet.

e.g.: if n = 3: "ABC" -> "DEF".

Since it has a very small keyspace (26^1), it can be easily broken, 
and Mallory could even guess or bruteforce the key.
(Note: You could choose a number higher than 26. However, this won't 
increase your keyspace since any number x will
be reduced to 1-26. See: (x - (26*(x // 26)).

Common letters in the german language are (in descending order):
"E","N","I","S","R" (subject to verification)

The statistical approach works well for long sentences since one has 
a greater samplesize for distribution analysis.
If two or more letters appear the same amount of times, you have to 
check which key is actually correct, either
by simply reading the outputs or running them against a 
distribution_dict of that language.

"""

ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
SPECIAL_CHARS = " ,.-;:_?!="

def encrypt(plain_text, key):
    """
    Encrypts plaintext using a caesar.

    :param plain_text:  The plaintext
    :param key: The key (Integer)
    :return: The cipher-text
    """
    cipher_text = ""
    for letter in plain_text:
        if letter in SPECIAL_CHARS:
            cipher_text += letter
            continue
        index = ALPHABET.find(letter.upper())
        new_index = flatten(index + key)
        cipher_text += ALPHABET[new_index]
    return cipher_text

def decrypt(cipher_text, key=None):
    """
    This function decrypts plaintext. If no key is specified, it 
    will be found using distribution analysis.
    :param cipher_text: The cipher-text
    :param key: The key
    :return: the plain-text
    """
    if key is None:
        key = find_key_from_cipher(cipher_text)

    plain_text = ""
    for letter in cipher_text:
        #Skipping special characters (incomplete solution)
        if letter in SPECIAL_CHARS:
            plain_text += letter
            continue
        index = ALPHABET.find(letter.upper())
        new_index = flatten(index - key)
        plain_text += ALPHABET[new_index]

    return plain_text

def flatten(number) :
    """
    Flattens the key back to be in range(1,26)
    :param number: 
    :return: 
    """
    return number - (26*(number//26))


def find_key_from_cipher(cipher_text):
    index_of_most_common_letter = 4 #Index of 'e'

    #Calculate distribution
    distribution_dict = analyse_letter_distribution(cipher_text)
    #Get common letters
    common_letters = sorted(distribution_dict, key=distribution_dict.get, reverse=True)

    #Use most common letter to get key
    key = ALPHABET.find(common_letters[0].upper()) - index_of_most_common_letter
    return key

def analyse_letter_distribution(cipher_text):
    distribution_dict = {}
    for letter in cipher_text:
        if letter in SPECIAL_CHARS:
            continue
        if letter not in distribution_dict:
            distribution_dict[letter] = 1
        else:
            distribution_dict[letter] += 1
    if len(distribution_dict.values()) != len(distribution_dict.values()):
        print("Multiple letters appear the same amount of times! Uh oh.")
    return distribution_dict


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        secret = encrypt("This sentence is encrypted. Encryption is broken     by using awesome encryption algorithms!",5)
        print(decrypt(secret))
```

One last note: Since it's a *statistical* analysis, this approach works best if the captured cipher-text is long.

One last last note: This description is a little incomplete (and formatting looks ugly, I'm on mobile.) I'd highly recommend this [german book](https://www.amazon.de/Kryptografie-Verfahren-Protokolle-Infrastrukturen-iX/dp/3864900158) by Klaus Schmeh for further reading.

Comment: im going to edit the code at the top okay 

it is able to open a file decrypt the text from that file and save it to another file

Comment: And now you'd only need to **copy & paste** `find_key_from_cipher` and its containing symbols and change your call to `decrypt(encrypted, find_key_from_cipher(encrypted))`.

Comment: can you edit my code at the top so i don't mess something up again