# Python caeser cipher function

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I want to write a python function that automatically finds the key of any encrypted text and decrypt the text. I want to use the caesar cipher encryption algorithm.

This code is such that, you will enter the rot but I want the code to be able to find the rot by automatically by itself.

```py
import string
from time import sleep

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase # "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def decrypt(text, rot):
    
    decrypted_text = "" 
    ct = open("rfc8446.txt", "r")

    for cipher in text:

        if cipher in alphabet:  # check if character is an alphabet
            
            position = alphabet.find(cipher) # find the index position of each text 
               
            new_position = (position - rot) % 25 # find the new index position to decrypt
            
            new_character = alphabet[new_position] # 
            decrypted_text += new_character
        else:
            decrypted_text += cipher

    print(decrypted_text)
text = "hnbcnamjh vh krtn unoc vn knqrwm"
rot = 7
decrypt(text, rot)
```

Comment: Could you show what you've got already? As a hint you might want to look at ord() and chr() which gives you the ascii value of a letter or converts the number into a letter as well as the modulo operator % which lets you make sure you stay within the range of 0-26.

Comment: Actually ... the real goal of StackOverflow is you build a library of Questions and Answers that is useful to all people.  Helping people find bugs is incidental to the real goal.

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I found the interesting answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40976011/13739319

Answer (score 0):

this will give you all possible solutions, simply by looping for all rotations.

```
import string
from time import sleep


def decrypt(text):
    for rot in range(26):
        alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase # "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        decrypted_text = ""
        for cipher in text:
            if cipher in alphabet:
                position = alphabet.find(cipher)
                new_position = (position - rot) % 25
                new_character = alphabet[new_position]
                decrypted_text += new_character
            else:
                decrypted_text += cipher
        print(decrypted_text)


text = "hnbcnamjh vh krtn unoc vn knqrwm"
decrypt(text)
```

however finding the good one is way more complicated since you need to identify which solution "looks" english, using stuff like text plausibility matrices